# Problems logging in to site with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I'm trying to learn how to use Selenium to log into a site:Ingram-Micro. I made a script and it worked on a different page: `https://news.ycombinator.com/login`.

Now I'm trying to apply the same thing to Ingram-Micro and I'm stuck and I don't know what else to try. The problem I'm having is a error/message that says the submit element is not clickable, there is a accept cookies button on the bottom of the page which seems to be causing the problem.

I've tried to account for it but I always get error saying that element doesn't exist. Yet if I don't try to click on the accept cookies element I get the original error saying the submit button isn't clickable. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException 
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

url = "https://usa.ingrammicro.com/_layouts/CommerceServer/IM/Login.aspx? 
returnurl=//usa.ingrammicro.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

def login():
    USERNAME = 'email'
    PASSWORD = 'password'         
    element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('I ACCEPT')
    if element.is_displayed():
        print("Element found")
        element.click()
    else:
        print("Element not found")

driver.find_element_by_id('okta-signin-username').send_keys(USERNAME)
driver.find_element_by_id('okta-signin-password').send_keys(PASSWORD)
driver.find_element_by_id('okta-signin-submit').click()      

login()

try:   
    me = driver.find_element_by_id("login_help-about")  
    print(f"{me.text} Element found")

except NoSuchElementException:
    print('Not found')

driver.quit()
```

Here are the errors I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input class="button button-primary" type="submit" value="Log in" id="okta-signin-submit" data-type="save"> is not clickable at point (365, 560). Other element would receive the click: <p class="cc_message">...</p>

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"link text","selector":"I ACCEPT"}
(Session info: headless chrome=84.0.4147.125)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge you face is synchronisation around scripts.

The chain of events on this site is 1) the page is loaded, 2) it kicks off it's javascript, 3) that slides the cookie window into view...

However, after the page is loaded, selenium doesn't know about the scripts so it thinks it is good to go. It's trying to click the button before it's there and gets upset that it can't find it. (`NoSuchElementException`)

There are different sync strategies - What works here is a webdriverwait to tell selenium to wait (without error) until that your object reached the specified expected conditions.

You can read more about waits and expected conditions [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Try this code.
For the cookie "I ACCEPT" button, I changed the identifier to xpath (since i like xpaths) and wrapped it in webdriverwait, waiting for the object to be clickable...

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException 
import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

url = "https://usa.ingrammicro.com/_layouts/CommerceServer/IM/Login.aspx?returnurl=//usa.ingrammicro.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

def login():
    USERNAME = 'email'
    PASSWORD = 'password'  

    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[text()="I ACCEPT"]')))       
    if element.is_displayed():
        print("Element found")
        element.click()
    else:
        print("Element not found")

    driver.find_element_by_id('okta-signin-username').send_keys(USERNAME)
    driver.find_element_by_id('okta-signin-password').send_keys(PASSWORD)
    driver.find_element_by_id('okta-signin-submit').click()      

login()
```

Note that i had to remove headless to check it worked and there are 3 additional imports at the top.

---

Webdriverwait is great when you don't have lots of complicated objects, or have ojects with different wait conditions.

An alternative sync and (Easier in my opionin) is to set an implicit wait ONCE at the start of your script - and this configures the driver objecct.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

As that link earlier says:

> An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount
> of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately
> available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is
> set for the life of the WebDriver object.

You can use it like this .. not doing all the code, just add this one line added after you create your driver and your code worked:

```
.....
url = "https://usa.ingrammicro.com/_layouts/CommerceServer/IM/Login.aspx?returnurl=//usa.ingrammicro.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds

def login():
    USERNAME = 'email'
    PASSWORD = 'password'  

    element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('I ACCEPT')
    if element.is_displayed():
        print("Element found")
        element.click()
    else:
        print("Element not found")
........
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to click on the div above the input. try somethin like this:

```
child = driver.find_element_by_id('okta-signin-submit')
parent = child.find_element_by_xpath('..') # get the parent
parent.click() # click parent element
```

UPDATE: This worked great on geckodrive without headless, but not with chromedrive. so instead i've tried something else. Instead of clicking the button, lets just hit enter in the form and submit it this way:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
...
driver.find_element_by_id('okta-signin-username').send_keys(USERNAME)
password_field = driver.find_element_by_id('okta-signin-password')
password_field.send_keys(PASSWORD)
password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I added that to my code and it returns a similar error to what Ive gotten before:  selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="o-form-button-bar">...</div> is not clickable at point (365, 557). Other element would receive the click: <p class="cc_message">...</p>

Comment: i could successfully click the link, but i'm using the firefox geckodriver for this. I will try to do it with chrome in a minute: https://imgur.com/gHd12cx

Comment: hey, i've made some tests and updated my answer, let me know if this helped

Comment: This worked really well, I dont need the time delay with this method, nice work!